# How do I add a dependency on a script to a target in CMake?

Tags: cmake

After my program is linked I need to perform some post-processing on it. I added a `add_custom_command(TARGET ...` and that worked fine. However, this extra custom command runs a script (that is not generated; it's checked into the codebase), and I want the target to be considered out of date if that script changes so it will be rebuilt properly.

The `add_dependencies` rule seems to only work between top-level elements, which this is not (it's just a script), and there's no `DEPENDS` element in this form of the `add_custom_command` that I can use.

How do I do this?

Comment: how about adding your script as a target as well?

Comment: How does one add a script as a target?

Comment: Actually I was thinking about the Makefile structure, but CMake offers an alternative signature for `add_custom_command` which is `add_custom_command(OUTPUT your_target COMMAND ./your_script.sh [...] MAIN_DEPENDENCY your_script.sh [...]`

Comment: But I don't see how to do that because I'm trying to add a command to an existing target.  That is, I already have an `add_executable()` statement for `your_target` above, so I can't add a new one like this.  The script doesn't create any extra output.  I could try to fake something.

Comment: Oops! Just fixing what I said in the first place, your script should be SOURCE (and not TARGET) so that as soon as CMake detects a change in one of the sources (in this case, your script), it runs the command again. (Sorry for the mess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately a bit convoluted, but you can use [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) to invoke CMake in script-processing mode via [`-P`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-Pfile).

You need to use `add_custom_target` here since it will *always* execute, even if everything's up to date.

Having made this decision, we need to have the custom target execute commands which will check for a new version of your post-processing script file (let's call this "my_script" and assume it's in your root dir), and if it's changed cause your dependent target to go out of date.

This would comprise:

1. Compare a previous copy of "my_script" to the current "my_script" in the source tree.  If the current "my_script" is different, or if the copy doesn't exist (i.e. this is the first run of CMake) then...
2. Copy "my_script" from the source tree to the build tree, and...
3. Touch a source file of the dependent target so that it goes out of date.

All of the commands required inside the CMake script can be achieved using [`execute_process`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process) to invoke [`cmake -E`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-E).

So the CMake script (called e.g. "copy_script.cmake") would be something like:

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files
                    ${OriginalScript} ${CopiedScript} RESULT_VARIABLE Result)
if(Result)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                      ${OriginalScript} ${CopiedScript})
  execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch_nocreate ${FileToTouch})
endif()
```

The CMake script needs to have required variables passed in via the [`-D`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#opt%3a-Dvar%3atypevalue) args *before* calling `-P`, so the calling CMakeLists.txt would have something like:

```
set(FileToTouch ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

add_custom_target(CopyScript ALL ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
                      -DOriginalScript=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script
                      -DCopiedScript=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/my_script
                      -DFileToTouch=${FileToTouch}
                      -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_script.cmake)

add_executable(MyExe ${FileToTouch})
```

This will cause a full rebuild of the executable, since it thinks a source file has been modified.  If you only require to force relinking there may be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Ouch.  If I was using `make` I would just add the script as a prerequisite to the executable target.  OK, I'll see if I can work something out.  Or, maybe I'll give up and just tell people they have to force the re-link by hand if they change the script.  If nothing else I learned a lot of cmake reading this!